# Closure: 'How long will online flight search engines need to feature and include NewLeaf?'

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, close-reasons

Can [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72025/13759) be reopened please?

I emphasise [the reasons](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72025/how-long-will-online-flight-search-engines-need-to-feature-and-include-newleaf#comment155654_72025) generously stated by user 'mts'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes — but please be patient!

Much like closing, reopening takes five explicit votes from users to occur. Typically, users will browse the newest or active questions which will mean that they quickly see questions which are close-worthy, leading to a rather low barrier of closure. Questions to be reopened are not often recently edited and thus don’t necessarily appear on these lists. Your’s was last edited ten hours ago as of posting this, so it has already fallen off the first site and off many people’s radar. And, of course, many see the magic brackets saying [on hold], and don’t even bother opening the question.

To combat that, there is a review queue, into which questions get put that gained a reopen vote or were edited within the first seven days of getting closed. This review queue will explicitly ask the users looking at it to make a decision: Leave closed or reopen. But again, people need to actively go looking for it. I have no idea how keen and eager other users are to go through it. (I personally hog review queues on all sites where I can see them.)

So you have two processes but both *take time*.

Be patient, grab a cup of tea. Chances are that your question will be reopened soon™.